# Npm install with local dependency and package-lock.json throws error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a three npm project:

- project **a** with underscore dependency
- project **b** with underscore and **a** local dependency
- project **c** with underscore, **a** and **b** dependency.

i have script which runs npm install for a, b and c project.

if running script for first time - ok

But if removing all node_modules folders, and run npm install in sequence - c npm install crashes with error:

```
ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path D:\npm sample\c\node_modules\.staging\underscore-df67550f
npm ERR! dest D:\npm sample\a\node_modules\underscore
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\npm sample\c\node_modules\.staging\underscore-df67550f' -> 'D:\npm sample\a\node_modules\underscore'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

You can download script and projects [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1414)

UPDATE:
package.json from project **a**:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "1.8.3"
  }
}
```

package.json from project **b**:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "a": "file:..//a"
  }
}
```

package.json from project **c**:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "a": "file:..//a",
    "b": "file:..//b"
  }
}
```

UPDATE
Problem is solving here - https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1414

Comment: What is on the package.json file?

Comment: Bathiya, I update my question.

Comment: Hi, so what exactly are you trying to achieve with this setup? That might help us understand the context.

Comment: @MwamiTovi, We have 3 projects A, B, C. Project A depends on both B & C, and project B depends on C. Projects B & C are public npm packages. In local development we want to use projects B & C in project C as npm modules but as direct links to avoid publishing B&C when code is changed there (we often make changes there).